# Alert for Domain Admin logon

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm looking for a way to send out an email alert for when a member of the "Domain Admins" group logs on.  We are running Server 2012 R2, is there anything built into Windows Server that can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's nothing built in.

Depending on why you want to do this, the easiest way to send an email whenever a domain admin logs in would probably be a logon script in group policy assigned to members of the domain admins group.  Powershell has [Send-MailMessage](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849925.aspx), which could send an email with the servername/computername and the logged on user as variables.

Be aware, though, that it's easy for domain admins to bypass group policy because domain admins can edit group policy.  So as a security feature, it's not amazingly useful.  If you're instead trying to track privilege escalation for some change management purpose and all the domain admins are on board with this, it might be okay.

If you're instead looking for intrusion detection, a dedicated security program (like [Advanced Threat Analytics](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/advanced-threat-analytics/)) might be a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

Builtin to Windows?  No.  That would be a custom code/script solution.  Event logs would need to be collected, and when there is a logon event from an account known to be a member of Domain Admins, send an email.

This is probably not an effective solution due to:

Domain Admins group gets most privileges via membership in the builtin domain Administrators group.  So if an account were a member of Administrators, it would seem to merit the same level of alerting.

Depending on the event id's that are in-scope for alerts, there could be a lot of events.  Specifically, there could be a lot of Network logons (type 3).

Filtering out network events/only alerting on interactive logons would exclude activity that occurs due to cached credentials/stolen credential hashes.